# Wordpress order by multiple ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type with date and time fields (which are strings for whatever reason)

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'camp', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat' => $cats, 'meta_key' => 'start_date', 'orderby'    => array( 'start_time' => 'ASC', 'start_date' => 'ASC') ) );
```

This is ordering the posts by start date but the start times are all out of sorts. It seems I can order by one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Check how `order_by` and `order` work. You need to put `ASC` or `DESC` on `order` config, then `order_by` needs to take one of the accepted values in the list. Here is the reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

I believe if you want to order by some custom meta data you need a meta query, check this out: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters